# Samsung ml-1665 cannot stop printing

Tags: printing, samsung

I cant stop printing. Under printer options when I click stop button nothing happens. And when I turn printer off and back on then it keeps printing the unfinished job. Is there any other way to stop printing jobs? My printer is Samsung ml-1665

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this as follows:

1. Turn off your printer.
2. Press and hold the feed button.
3. Then press the power button while holding the feed button for 10s.
               Maybe there is some blinking (mine had nothing).
4. Turn on again. (Should be clean and ready!)

I hope that helps someone, I've been struggling with that for years.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should delete the printer and install it again using this guide: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11056485&postcount=2

Comment: At the moment I haven't installed any driver from Samsung. I think my printer is supported out of the box and I wouldn't like to install anything else. I hope there is a better solution

Comment: Installing the official drivers from manufacturers is always a good idea when stuck. I dont get the fact that you do not want to try it?